# Netbeans deploy javaFX project to tomcat automatically

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, javafx-8

For "Java Web Application" project, I can right-click the web project and select "Run".
Netbeans will deploy web application to tomcat (which is installed by Netbeans) and open
"http : //localhost/myApp" in browser.

For "JavaFX" project, the "Run" option can execute program in 3 ways:

1. Standalone
2. as Web Start
3. in Browser

With option "3. in Browser",  NetBeans will open "file:///myAppLocation/dist/JavaFXApplication3.html".

What should I do, if I want NetBeans to deploy JavaFX application (JNDI、*.Jar、*.html) to local tomcat and run in browser?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the output directory of the project i.e. dist.dir value.

Goto ./nbproject folder 
open project.properties.
change dist.dir=dist to ../webapps/ROOT directory of you tomcat installation.

Note: the file path separator should be "/" not "\"